# I get NullPointerException in an Android animation?

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-animation

I have the following code in the `getView(...)` method of a ListView Adapter for animating the rows of a ListView:

```
float initialTranslation = (mLastPosition <= position ? 500f
                : -500f);

        rowView.setTranslationY(initialTranslation);
        ViewPropertyAnimator animator = rowView.animate();
        animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
        animator.translationY(0f);
        animator.setDuration(500l);
        animator.setListener(null);

        mLastPosition = position;
```

In emulator Platform 3.2 (API13) I get the following run time error when the code reaches to line **animator.translationY(0f);**

```
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animatePropertyBy(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:614)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animateProperty(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:564)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.translationY(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:426)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at org.mabna.dashboard.ui.adapters.AdapterReportCentersYearly.getView(AdapterReportCentersYearly.java:66)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1970)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1756)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:656)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:716)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1595)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1800)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9581)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1282)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2040)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-31 15:24:48.024: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My application works fine on device 4.2.2

How can I solve that?

Comment: `animator.translationY(0f);` I believe this is causing the NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by other answer this is a [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18803) reported.

try using :

```
        rowView.setTranslationY(initialTranslation);
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rowView, "translationY", 0f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
        anim.setDuration(500l).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:
`

```
animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
        animator.translationY(0f);
        animator.setDuration(500l);
        animator.setListener(null);
```

with:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rowView, null, 1f, 0f).setDuration(5001).start()
```

Comment: `null` is ambiguous. I wrote `String aaa = null;
   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rowView, aaa, 1f, 0f).setDuration(5001)
     .start();`  and get exactly the same error :(

Comment: Try to write "alpha" instead of null